# Did China colonize any countries?

Tags: china, colonization, asia

A lot of Asian countries used to use the Chinese alphabet to write such as Japan or Vietnam, were there any countries actually colonized by China that is not apart of modern day China?

Comment: During the [Warring States Period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period), "chinese" culture was in the north. After that, it spread south. One could consider the conquest of the south as colonization. Different time period then when Europeans did it.  Later, between 1400 - 1800, they also expanded into Yuanan, Tibet, and Xingjian, and Dongbei. This could be colonization as well. Depends how you define colonization.

Comment: This question needs to define "colonized" and also "country" since the modern notion of statehood is entirely inappropriate for most of history, and also "China" (does Taiwan count? does the Mongol Empire count?)

Comment: You mean like Tibet?

Comment: @SPavel Taiwan would certainly count as the Chinese only appear to have colonised it during the 17th century. They held it for 200 years before it became part of Japan. It was Japanese for about 50 years and then was taken over by China at the end of WWII. With the communist takeover of the mainland four years later the nationalist remnant fled to Taiwan.

Comment: @DamionKeeling  - it was definitely *colonized* but was it a *country* by OP's definition? And is it a part of modern day China? The PRC would tell you "yes" which excludes it from OP's criteria.

Comment: @SPavel Claiming another country belongs to you despite it never being under the dominion of your government does not make the claim valid or even true. It would be better to argue that the ROC originally claimed to represent the whole of China thereby making Taiwan part of China. As Taiwan is not part of the PRC and it would seem the China in the question is the PRC then "modern day China" would appear to exclude the ROC.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on whom you ask.

The Chinese monarchy defined itself as the 'middle kingdom' in the center of the world (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_China#Middle_Kingdom) for the name and problems with it) and expected foreigners to defer to China. This colored their intercourse with other countries, where an exchange of goods would be filed as 'tribute' and 'gifts to a vassal' by China. The other country might have filed the same event as 'diplomatic exchange of gifts with a foreign king.'

The case of [Korea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseon#China) is closer to what you describe, but again the nature is not comparable to 19th century colonialism. Yet Korea did acknowledge the subordinate relationship.

Vietnam was also under Chinese control [for some time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vietnam#Dynastic_Vietnam).